# Include googleVis chart in ioslides RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, presentation, googlevis

I have a following chart:

```
library(googleVis)
df = data.frame(models = c("PLAT", "LC", "APC", "CBD", "M6", "M7", "M8"), val = 1:7)
Column <- gvisColumnChart(df)
plot(Column)
```

I would like to place it in ioslides in RStudio.
Can anyone instruct me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use `options(gvis.plot.tag='chart')` as part of your code, this instructs the `plot()` function to only output the html code for the chart. Here is the code:

````
## Another GoogleVis Slide

Some text in slide

```{r warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis', tidy=FALSE}
library(googleVis)

op <- options(gvis.plot.tag = 'chart')

df = data.frame(models = c("PLAT", "LC", "APC", "CBD", "M6", "M7", "M8"), val = 1:7)
Column <- gvisColumnChart(df)
plot(Column)
```
````

You can find this by typing `?plot.gvis` but I think it is not evident, so hopefully someone will save some time by reading this answer